# Grep for a number of n digits after a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, cut

```
Release build trunk.965997 (965997) - 155mc13bcf03t - 2016-04-13T14:46:44.823+0000
```

I need to grep or cut from the output of a command (like above) & get the output as 965997 only whereas this number can be of 6 or 7 digits only but will be always followed by trunk.

Comment: You're supposed to show your work and ask for what didn't work.

Comment: This number appears twice in the output. Which one would you like to get?

Comment: Is the result you need? `grep -E "trunk\.[0-9]{6,7}" | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1`

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep -oP`:

```
s='Release build trunk.965997 (965997) - 155mc13bcf03t - 2016-04-13T14:46:44.823+0000'
grep -oP 'trunk\.\K\d+' <<< "$s"

965997
```

i.e. find `trunk.` text which is followed by 1 or more digits. It uses `\K` to reset matched information after `trunk.` and prints only digits that are followed.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
echo "Release build trunk.965997 (965997) - 155mc13bcf03t - 2016-04-13T14:46:44.823+0000" | sed -n 's/.*\.\([0-9]\{6,7\}\).*/\1/p'
```

Also if you can rely on this number to always be between the parenthesis:

```
sed -n 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/p'
```